slice charts for embedded submanifold of a manifold with boundary
On page 104 of the book Introduction to Smooth Manifold ,second edition, written by John M. Lee, the author said that if $M$ is a smooth manifold with nonempty boundary and $S\subseteq M$ is an embedded submanifold, then $S$ might intersect $\partial M$ in complicated ways. I'd like to ask whether there is an example shows what complicated way can make an embedded submanifold of a manifold with boundary fail to satisfy local k-slice condition.
